# References seem broken in ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

I had a computer problem and needed to rebuild it. After that I restored my ASP.NET project on the newly built computer.

Even though the assemblies are in the bin folder of the project, my references seem to be broken.
[image]

One article suggested that I'd go to Project -> Properties -> Reference Paths and enter the folder there. I tried it but it didn't help.

When I compile the solution, I'm also getting an "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed message.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

--- UPDATE ---
Because I built the computer fresh with Windows 10, I noticed that I don't have .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on the computer -- see below:
[image]

I tried targeting .NET Framework 4.6 but that didn't help either.

--- UPDATE 2 ---
I've been trying to force reinstall packages one by one but it's like I'm chasing my tail. I keep getting all kinds of errors, like this one:
[image]

--- UPDATE 3 ---
This is very strange. As you can see in the first image, the System.Net.Http.Extensions seems to be missing.

[image]

However, if I try to reinstall it through package manager console, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: I think i have had something similar in the past. I remember fixing it by manually going to the root solution folder and deleting everything in the packages folder, then using nuget to redownload.

Comment: Yikes!!! I was hoping there was an easier solution! Thank you for your response anyway.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. I get "All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore" message.

Comment: You can force a reinstall by typing `Update-Package –reinstall` in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Looks like that messed things up even more. Now some of the assemblies are removed from my references. For example the AWSSDK is no longer there.

Comment: Should I try installing .NET 4.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can force reinstall a package in Package Manager Console.

```
Update-Package –reinstall DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
```

[image]

If you have a lot of dependencies, the easiest way is to copy and paste them *(from packages.config)* into notepad and make it like this -

```
Update-Package –reinstall DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
Update-Package –reinstall DotNetOpenAuth.Core
...
```

Then copy and past all of them into Package Manager Console at once.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this is not working for me either. See my update 2 in the original post. I was pretty sure this would work.

Comment: @Sam If you change the target to .Net 4.6, some packages become invalid. It will make it worst. Easiest way is to remove everything inside package folder, and do the above step again.

Comment: I removed the contents of the packages folder. When I opened the project, it restored quite a few on its own so I was hopeful. At the end, I was still missing quite a few references. I tried reinstalling System.Net.Http.Extenstion and ended up getting an error message -- see UPDATE 3

Answer (score 0):

I have recently reported the following at Microsoft Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2652426/nuget-leaving-back-garbage-task-in-project-that-causes-non-nuget-references-and-build-to-fail

Could try my workarround mentioned there to see if it fixes those references for you

Comment: in case you wonder how I had found what was causing the issue, the answer is version control, always use such and see diffs in case something bad like this happens, to see what has caused it

Comment: the task in my case was "EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports", I see you mention "EnsureBindingRedirects", so you could also search for that one in the project file